# Oauth2 twitter api php-curl returns null

Tags: php, twitter, oauth-2.0, php-curl

im newbie in twitter api and php curl.
Im trying to authorize in oauth2…but im stuck on second step, the request didnt redirect and so i cant get the code and state.

Here is my code following the instructions of this tutorial: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/authorization-code

```
function random() {
    return (float)rand()/(float)getrandmax();
  }

/**
 * Generates a random string containing numbers and letters
 * @param  {number} length The length of the string
 * @return {string} The generated string
 */
function generateRandomString ( $length) 
{
    $text = '';
    $possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
  
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      $text[$i]=$possible[floor(random() * strlen($possible))];
    }
    return base64_encode($text);
  };

/* *The userid and password are separated by a single colon (":") character within a base64 encoded string in the credentials.


If the user agent wishes to send the Client ID "Aladdin" and password "open sesame,” it would use the following header field:

      
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ== 

    

To create the basic authorization header you will need to base64 encoding on your Client ID and Client Secret which can be 
obtained from your App’s “Keys and Tokens” page inside of the developer portal.*/
   
$client_id='cFo1S1g4azUweVJzWFBBcEx1LVE6MTpjaQ';

$client_secret='OdvBpQG60W5UPpRMyAIPMSFZc2zWf8NcGIXCcPs_bdaz7906IK';

$authorizationHeader = 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($client_id . ':' . $client_secret);


/*
Steps to connect using OAuth 2.0
Step 1: Construct an Authorize URL

Your App will need to build an authorize URL to Twitter, indicating the scopes your App needs to authorize. 
For example, if your App needs to lookup Tweets, users and to manage follows, it should request the following scopes:

tweet.read%20users.read%20account.follows.read%20account.follows.write

The URL will also contain the code_challenge and state parameters, in addition to the other required parameters. 
In production you should use a random string for the code_challenge.

*/

$code_challenge = generateRandomString(8);

//%20 sino en espacio en blanco. si quieres offline acces se lo añades, si no por defecto no pones nada y es online access
$scope="tweet.read%20users.read%20account.follows.read%20account.follows.write"; 

/*
Step 2: GET oauth2/authorize

Have the user authenticate and send the application an authorization code. If you have enabled OAuth 2.0 for your App 
you can find your Client ID inside your App’s “Keys and Tokens” page.

An example URL to redirect the user to would look like this:

https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code
                        &client_id=M1M5R3BMVy13QmpScXkzTUt5OE46MTpjaQ
                        &redirect_uri=https://www.example.com
                        &scope=tweet.read%20users.read%20follows.read%follows.write
                        &state=state
                        &code_challenge=challenge
                        &code_challenge_method=plain
*/ 
$endpoint='https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize';
$redirect_uri='http://localhost:8080/callback/logintwitter.php';
$params = array('response_type' => 'code', 
                'client_id' => $client_id, 
                'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri, 
                'scope' => $scope, 
                'state' => 'state', 
                'code_challenge' => $code_challenge, 
                'code_challenge_method' => 'plain' );

$url = $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query($params);
echo '</br>';
        echo '<h2> URL </h2>';
        echo $url;
        echo '</br>';
    //Inicio curl
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
  // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$authorizationHeader);

    //resultado de peticion
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //Gestion de errores
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        print "Error: " . curl_error($ch);
        echo 'Error en ch curl';
    } else {
        // Show me the result Info de la peticion CURL ...se podria quitar mas adelante
        echo 'ch curl Info';
        echo '<h4> Info Curl </h4>';
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

        echo '</br>';
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($info, true) . '</pre>';
        // echo 'Took ', $info['total_time'], ' seconds to send a request to ', $info['url'], "\n";
        //El resultado de la consulta que devuelve un json, se pasa a variable php
        //json_decode Convierte un string codificado en JSON a una variable de PHP. 
        $json = json_decode($result);

        //Resultado consulta...puedo acceder de la forma json->access_token
        echo '</br>';
        echo '<h2> Resultado consulta </h2>';
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($json, true) . '</pre>';
        echo '</br>';

        var_dump($result);

        //Tengo que recoger state y code
        //Upon successful authentication, the redirect_uri  you would receive a request containing the auth_code parameter. 
        //Your application should verify the state parameter.

        //An example request from client’s redirect would be:

        //https://www.example.com?state=state&code=VGNibzFWSWREZm01bjN1N3dicWlNUG1oa2xRRVNNdmVHelJGY2hPWGxNd2dxOjE2MjIxNjA4MjU4MjU6MToxOmFjOjE
        
    }

    //Cierro CURl
    curl_close($ch);
```

As if for educational purpose, im a techer in vocational education, dont mind about client_id and data…i have an app for tests, and if i have problems id regenerate the keys.

My app is from yesterday,so by default it has oauth2 activated.
As far as i know, twitter should redirect to my http://localhost:8080/callback/logintwitter.php and send two params code and state.

Someone told me that twitter cant redirect to localhost, something i havent read in the tutorial or anywhere else...just in case i changed redirect url to:
'https://votacionya.000webhostapp.com/callback/logintwitter.php' just in case

I got stuck in my script…i have as return result an array with no values...

Any help would be apreciated.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english…

Comment: Ever figure this out?  Having trouble with changing over to v2 myself right now and can't find much information.